# Apache Flink Recommend approach for handling external API calls with KeyedProcessFunction

Tags: apache-flink

I am quite new to Flink and have a question regarding making external API calls from a KeyedProcessedFunction's `processElement` function.

In our current setup, we are making synchronous API calls to an upstream service, while updating the `KeyedProcessFunction`'s state accordingly based on the response received. This works for now, but I am wondering if it's the best way to go about it.

From what I understand, the recommended approach in Flink for handling external data access is to use the Asynchronous IO API. However, I am not too sure how I'd be able to fit this into our use case without some sort of refactoring, considering `RichAsyncFunction` is stateless.

What would be the best way to go about this? Or is `KeyedProcessFunction` not suited for this purpose in the first place? Thank you.

Example code to illustrate my point:

```
public class StoppingLight extends KeyProcessedFunction<String, String>  {
  
    private ValueState<String> previousState;
     
     .....
   @Override
    public void processElement(String newState, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) {
        // getNextState() is a synchrnous HTTPS API call to some external endpoint
        String nextState = getNextState(newState, previousState.value());     
  
        if(nextState == "Red") {
           this.previousState = "Yellow";
        } else if(nextState == "Green") {
           this.previousState= "Red";
        } 
    } 
}
```

I thought about taking the http request out of the KeyedProcessFunction, and chaining it against an async-io operator somehow, but that probably wouldn't work because the business logic needs to get the return value from the API call in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Doing synchronous API calls from any Flink user function (such as a KeyedProcessFunction) is not recommended, because this interferes with checkpointing. The operator involved can't do anything while the user function is blocked waiting on the synchronous I/O. Even if it works fine most of the time, this risks causing checkpoint failures. Not to mention poor throughput and resource utilization.

However, I'm not sure what to recommend as an alternative. (Not sure why asynchronous I/O isn't a good option for your use case.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Our KeyedProcessFunction keeps track of a ValueState that gets updated based on the return value of an external API call. The business logic in the processElement function is: Call an API with this input, gets a response and update the ValueState with some data from the API call. 

However, RichAsyncFunctions , seems to work with DataStreams as opposed to discrete elements, and I am not too sure if asyc functions are capable of tracking state the way KeyedProcessFunctions can.

Comment: You can always have your Async Function generate a result that's used to update the ValueState in a downstream operator.